# How would i not update a image from my files and database?

Tags: php, database, file

I run into this problem sometimes with the update form which contains files to upload to a database.
now to explain :I have a submit form with two input Fields. The first input is the name of the image , and the second one is the image itself. The form is submitted to upload.php as you can see the code

upload.php

```
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){

    include 'connection.php';

    $imageName=$_POST['imageName'];
    $image=$_FILES['image'];

    $imageTmpName=$image['tmp_name'];
    $imageName=$image['name'];

    $imageExt=explode('.',$imageName);
    $imageExt=strtolower(end($imageExt));

    $newImageName=uniqid('',true).'.'.$imageExt;
    $path='C:/xampp/htdocs/test/img/'.$newImageName;

    if(move_uploaded_file($imageTmpName,$path)){
        echo 'file moved';

    }

    $query="INSERT INTO imagedata(imageName,image) VALUES ('$imageName','$newImageName')";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
        echo 'data posted to database';
    }
}
```

You can see from the code that I am moving the image temporary name to my path and in the same time I'm and storing the new image name into the database.
I am using the same principle update the image name and the image itself in a new form that is submit to update.php as show below:

```
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

    include 'connection.php';

    $uImageName=$_POST['uimageName'];
    $uImage=$_FILES['uImage'];

    $uImageTmpName=$Image['tmp_name'];
    $uImageName=$uImage['name'];

    $uImageExt=explode('.',$uImageName);
    $uImageExt=strtolower(end($uImageExt));

    $uNewImageName=uniqid('',true).'.'.$uImageExt;
    $uPath='C:/xampp/htdocs/test/img/'.$uNewImageName;

    if(move_uploaded_file($uImageTmpName,$uPath)){
        echo 'file updatet';

    }

    $query="UPDATE imagedata SET imageName='$uImageName',image='$uNewImageName'";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
        echo 'data updatet to database';
    }
}
```

Remember that I am querying database and echo the values  inside the input field values itself.Now the problem occurs in the update.php file, whenever i update the image name without uploading any new image, it will update the database with a blank image and return that to my update form.

So what i want to do is  whenever i want to update the database without an image from my update    form, i want the previous uploaded image to remain the same. Or if i want a new image to be uploaded to the database then i want the database to be updated with the new image and also to delete the old image that i have previous uploaded.
I want to thank you for your help with this

Comment: You realize that you're updating your entire database without a WHERE clause.

Comment: yes i should use the $id='$updateId'; in the update query , but still this doesn't give me the solution with the update form submission where i don't upload any image

Comment: Ok.  Well, someone gave an answer below, see that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple way to keep old image if new image not selected!

Here is the easy way, create a hidden input and echo your old image name in value, and keep new image value empty as follows:

```
<input type="hidden" name="YourOldFile" value="YourOldFileName">
<input type="file" name="YourNewFile" value="">
```

Then do if statement in PHP part:

```
if(!empty($POST['YourNewFile'])) {
   $newFile = $_POST['YourNewFile'];
   // Then do your update query with uploading new image here and delete old image from the server.
} else {
   $YourOldFileName = $_POST['YourOldFile'];
   //Then do your query here with oldname and do not delete image from server.
}
```

Note: you can do same for insert and update, and you need to set where clause for update query.

**UPDATE :**

Displaying with or without image extention is a different question because its a part of your upload code, and how you save and display.
So, your codes in page looks like this :

```
include 'connection.php';

if(!empty($_FILES['uImageName'])) {
   // Then do your update query with uploading new image here and delete old image from the server.
    if(isset($_POST['update'])){

        $uImageName=$_FILES['uimageName'];
//Your upload code doesnt look right coded to me, I would use an upload class, You can search for how to upload image
// I use verot upload class its very simple.

        $uImageTmpName=$Image['tmp_name'];
        $uImageName=$uImage['name'];

        $uImageExt=explode('.',$uImageName);
        $uImageExt=strtolower(end($uImageExt));

        $uNewImageName=uniqid('',true).'.'.$uImageExt;
        $uPath='C:/xampp/htdocs/test/img/'.$uNewImageName;

        if(move_uploaded_file($uImageTmpName,$uPath)){
            echo 'file updated';

        }

        $query="UPDATE imagedata SET imageName='$uImageName'";
        if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
            echo 'data updatet to database';
        }
    }
} else {
   $YourOldFileName = $_POST['YourOldFile'];

   //Then do your query here with oldname and do not delete image from server.

    //Solution 1. You can update image column with your old image name.

    $query="UPDATE imagedata SET image='$YourOldFileName'";

    //Solution 2. You can update all other columns without image column dont update image column and dont include image column in your query.

    $query="UPDATE imagedata SET yourColumnName='$DataYouWantToInsert'";
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$query)){
        echo 'data updatet to database';
    }
}
```

```html
<form>
/*Your inputs here*/
<input type="hidden" name="YourOldFile" value="YourOldFileName">
<input type="file" name="YourNewFile" value="">
/*Your buttons*/
</form>
```

Read comments in code.

Comment: its a working example on my site, put all your codes in that if statements even upload part too. glad I helped

Comment: Dilek i have formulated one code that i am using now .Now first time when i upload the file it goes well , then the same picure when i update  it will echo out only the unique id without the 'jpg' extension. but the second time it keeps running well.